# I import java.math.*; but java still can't find the symbol sqrt(double)...?

Tags: java, recursion, prime-factoring

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.math.*;

class Factor
{
    public void Factor(double NumToFactor)
    {
        for (double i=0; i <= Math.sqrt(NumToFactor); i++)
        {
            if (NumToFactor%i == 0)
            {
                Factor(NumToFactor/i);
                System.out.println(i + "*");
            }
        }
    }

}

public class PrimeFactorization 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println(Factor(120.0)); 
    }
}
```

I get the following error (I'm confused):

error: cannot find symbol
        for (double i=0; i <= Math.sqrt(NumToFactor); i++)

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting a problem on the call to `Factor`, because it's in a different class? Note that calling a method the same as a class name is a really bad idea - as is giving a method or parameter a PascalCase name at all.

Comment: I tried this and I am not getting an error that says anything about `Math.sqrt`.  You might want to edit your question with a copy-and-paste of the _exact_ output you're seeing.

Comment: you don't need `import java.math.*;`

Comment: also the constructor of the class is `void` which is weird

Answer (score 5):

It is never necessary to import `java.lang` classes. `java.math` does not contain `Math`; `java.lang` does.

Your compile error does not say you are missing `Math`. Instead you have many other problems in this code, starting with the fact that you have a `void` return type on *what looks like something you might be trying to declare as a constructor but aren't* (edited). Constructors do not have a return type.

Comment: That's not a constructor - that's a void method which happens to share the same name. Horrible, but valid. (There are many *other* issues though...)

Comment: I changed the name of the method to Factorz, yet it still doesn't do anything. Why isn't it reading the symbol Math.sqrt?

Comment: @AdamStaples If you declare a (non-static) method in class `Factor`, you cannot call that method from outside `Factor` unless you give it an object of type `Factor`, i.e. `obj.Factorz(...)`.  (P.S. The convention is that method names should begin with lower-case letters.)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of problems with this code. First of all even after fixing you code it goes into infinte loop. Recursion logic is not correct. This is the quick fix I did ,so that you can call this method. But, `Factor()` method from Factor class you need to check with logic to break infinite loop ie. `Factor()` method calling `Factor()` , it is not ending.

See problem is not with Math.sqrt(), not beacuse of constructor. Logic that and also method has no return type.

```
class Factor
{
    public double Factor(double NumToFactor)
    {
        System.out.println(Math.sqrt(NumToFactor));
        for (double i=0; i <= Math.sqrt(NumToFactor); i++)
        {
            try{
            if (NumToFactor%i == 0)
            {
                //Factor(NumToFactor/i);
                System.out.println(i + "*");
            }
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
        }
        return NumToFactor;
    }

}

public class PrimeFactorization 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Factor f = new Factor();
        System.out.println(f.Factor(120.0)); 
    }
}
```